# displaying & editing datetime / datetime-tz in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

what is the best way to define and use dates , datetime and datetime-tz in emberjs ?

I can put

```
App.Customer  = DS.Model.extend({
  testDate: DS.attr('date', {defaultValue: '2013-09-13'),
  testDateTime: DS.attr('date', {defaultValue: '2013-09-13T20:47:20+01:00'),
```

into the model, but it seems to me that I can only put

```
{{input type="datetime-local"
```

into the template. this allows me to update the field according to the local time (which may not be what I want), but has a nice drop-down calendar and allows me to enter the time

Any other type (datetime-tz for example) seems to only show as a text input.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

`datetime-tz` is not a valid input type.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html

The way that `datetime-local` is styled is not part of the spec and is left up to the browser.

You might want to use something like the jQueryUI datepicker to ensure that things work the same across browsers.  In that case you could extend the `Ember.TextField` view to handle setting up and tearing down the datepicker widget.

```
App.DatePicker = Ember.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this.$().datepicker();
  },
  willDestroyElement : function(){
    this.$().datepicker('destroy');
  }
});

{{view App.DatePicker valueBinding="date"}}
```

Here's a JSBin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1054/edit